# Python-like Coding in C for Pointers

Tags: python, c, pointers

I am transitioning from Python to C, so my question might appear naive. I am reading [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-bindings-overview/) on Python-C bindings and it is mentioned that:

> In C, all parameters are pass-by-value. If you want to allow a function to change a variable in the caller, then you need to pass a pointer to that variable.

**Question**: Why cant we simply re-assign the values inside the function and be free from pointers?

The following code uses pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i = 24;

int increment(int *j){
    (*j)++;
    return *j;
}
void main() {
    increment(&i);
    printf("i = %d", i);
}
```

Now this can be replaced with the following code that doesn't use pointers:

```
int i = 24;

int increment(int j){
    j++;
    return j;
}
void main() {
    i=increment(i);
    printf("i = %d", i);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly. Are you claiming that the two code snippets are equivalent, or are you asking why they are not?

Comment: You are showing a legitimate coding style that frowns on side-effects in programs. It can help create (arguably) more parallelizable code with fewer errors. Some programming languages are built this way. If I have a structure in `foo` and pass `&foo` or `*foo`, I have to worry about the lifetime of `foo` and what the function is going to do to it. If I pass `foo`, so its copied, I don't have those concerns. STL components tend to copy alot, its happening under the covers frequently.

Comment: Or wait. Yes, that construct is equivalent. But it's a strange example. I mean, yes you can do that. But there are tons of other uses for pointers.

Comment: @tdelaney +1 Well thanks for sheding spotlight on that. Reading your comments in the answer below and the answer itself makes me wonder that there is a tradeoff between performance and convenience. So pointers might be good for performance and re-assignment for convenience. Right?

Comment: @klutt well I thought that could be the simplest reproducible example to illustrate a point and ask for a question.

Comment: @gfdsal - that question could lead to fist fights in the CS department. Suppose a shared structure with locks ended in deadlocks or priority inversion in a parallel system. Copies that decouple code can run faster even if you burn a few cycles getting there. When a pointer is passed to a function, who owns the buffer when the function returns? Buffer passing systems like message queues have complicated rules about that. When a message reaches its end point, does it need go get back to the original creator for freeing? Copying can make that less burdensome.

Comment: One of the things about python is that it has a single standard memory management system. If I pass a pointer in C, the receiver doesn't know whether that's something that can be freed or whether its part of a larger buffer. So, even if the data is to be consumed by the function, freeing is still the responsibility of the caller. If I pass a pointer to `send` in C for instance, the library is going to copy that data because it never takes ownership of the buffer itself.

Comment: Sometimes Python gives you both choices.  Look at `list.sort()` vs. `sorted(list)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only return one thing from a function. If you need to update multiple parameters, or you need to use the return value for something other than the updated variable (such as an error code), you need to pass a pointer to the variable.

Comment: You can return a struct, though. A functional programmer would frown on modifying data in pointers and may prefer this way of doing things.

Comment: @tdelaney I debated whether to mention that in my answer. Passing structs around by value is not very common in C programming, AFAIK.

Comment: I've done it in systems where we wanted to pass back return codes and return values. `go` has immortalized the practice. Also, people may be doing it more than they think when returning C++ STL objects. I agree, its not the normal way of doing things but `errno()` is horrible!

Comment: @Barmar, yes as tdelaney said, in Python I can return a tuple or an array that has multiple output values, I guess it makes sense with your answer "coupled with the answer below that we will be copying large array multiple times" right?

Comment: @gfdsal It's more common in languages like Python and JS because objects are passed by reference, there's no copying.

Comment: Allright. makes sense now. And bravo for 5 upvotes in 10 mins!

Comment: One of the great things about Python is the ease with which you can return multiple things from a function.  In C it's much more difficult, you have to define a structure to hold all the things.

Answer (score 2):

Getting this out of the way first - pointers are *fundamental* to C programming.  You cannot be “free” of pointers when writing C.  You might as well try to never use `if` statements, arrays, or any of the arithmetic operators.  You cannot use a substantial chunk of the standard library without using pointers.

“Pass by value” means, among other things, that the formal parameter `j` in `increment` and the actual parameter `i` in `main` are separate objects in memory, and changing one has absolutely no effect on the other.  The value of `i` is copied to `j` when the function is called, but any changes to `i` are not reflected in `j` and vice-versa.

We work around this in `C` by using pointers.  Instead of passing the value of `i` to `increment`, we pass its *address* (by value), and then dereference that address with the unary `*` operator.

This is one of the cases where we *have* to use pointers.  The other case is when we track dynamically-allocated memory.  Pointers are also useful (if not strictly required) for building containers (lists, trees, queues, stacks, etc.).

Passing a value as a parameter and returning its updated value works, but only for a single parameter.  Passing multiple parameters and returning their updated values in a `struct` type can work, but is not good style if you’re doing it *just* to avoid using pointers.  It’s also not possible if the function must update parameters *and* return some kind of status (such as the `scanf` library function, for example).

Similarly, using file-scope variables does not scale and creates maintenance headaches.  There are times when it’s not the wrong answer, but in general it’s not a good idea.

Comment: So its more of an adopted programming style/practice, as libraries in case of your answer, standard library is built around the intent of using pointers.

Comment: @gfdsal: It's not just a matter of style - we are *required* to use pointers in certain cases.  Pointers are a distinct class of data types.  Dynamically allocated memory is tracked through pointers.  Array subscripting is defined in terms of pointer semantics. Abstraction is accomplished through pointers.  Higher-order functions (i.e., functions that take other functions as arguments) require you to use pointers. Instead of finding creative ways to avoid using pointers, your time is better spent learning how they work and how to use them correctly.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the advice. I am actually learning about how to correctly use them.

Answer (score 1):

So, imagine you need to pass large arrays or other data structures that need modification. If you apply the way you use to increment an integer, then you create a copy of that large array for each call to that function. Obviously, it is not memory-friendly to create a copy, instead, we pass pointers to functions and do the updates on a single array or whatever it is.

Plus, as the other answer mentioned, if you need to update many parameters then it is impossible to return in the way you declared.

Comment: Allright. I guess it It does makes sense to avoid having to copy the large array and re-assign.